# Unicode characters in where condition - phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, unicode, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I'm sure this is something to do with how I've set the server up. Total server noob.

When I enter the query

```
SELECT * FROM `models` WHERE `sex` = 'x'
```

I get an error saying

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '&#039 x &#039 '

```
SELECT * FROM `models` WHERE `sex` = &#039 x  &#039
```

I have removed the ; from the code examples for clarity.

Is this a php.ini setting I need to change? Is this an input conversion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTML-encoding all input data is something quite a few (deeply misguided) PHP apps do, but phpMyAdmin doesn't and it is not a built-in PHP feature. However, `&#039;` suggests that *some* PHP component is doing it, because that's what `htmlspecialchars(..., HTML_ENTITIES)` outputs, where many other HTML encoders would produce the shorter `&#39;`. Do you have any other PHP apps/extensions/plugins/WAF-like filters installed that might be mangling the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use "html entities" when writing SQL.

`&#39;` is one way of encoding an apostrophe `'` for display on web pages.  I don't know how you go that into your code, but that seems to be the problem.

Only use the PHP function `htmlentities()` for writing to the web page.

What editor are you using?

**Edit**:

Check `php.ini`.  You may need `magic_quotes_gpc = Off`

Comment: I am entering standard ' characters. I am entering directly into a phpmyadmin SQL input textarea. The server ( I believe ) is converting the ' to #038/; I'm wondering if there is some php conversion on POST vars that is converting it. I have set UTF8 as the CHARSET on the Db but no solution as yet.

Comment: `magic_quotes` is `addslashes` escaping rather than HTML-encoding, though.

Comment: Then I don' know what is turning quotes into entities.

Comment: magic_quotes_gpc is Off. Would this be down to database charset? I've set UTF8 across the board. I'm sure it's server set up or the fact that I have imported an old db. Appreciate your time.